# Video Compression without MediaCodec

Tags: android, video-compression

How to lower the quality of video before uploading to server like UIIMagePickerController video quality in iOS?I have tried MediaCodec but it is taking long time.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use built-in capability of the platform (and also take advantage of hardware acceleration on the device) then you have to use `MediaCodec`.  The `MediaCodec` implementation is the same thing used by the built-in camera app, so there shouldn't be a huge performance problem within the framework.